# New England ISO API

Tags: python, json, api, energy

I am trying to pull data from the New England API
https://webservices.iso-ne.com/docs/v1.1/

When simply inputing this link in my browser (https://webservices.iso-ne.com/api/v1.1/hourlysysload/current.json) I get a JSON response after being asked my credentials. However when using this code in Python I have an error

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
url = 'https://webservices.iso-ne.com/api/v1.1/hourlysysload/current.json'
r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(myusername, mypassword))
```

Here is the error:

```
SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

Comment: your ssl library wasn't able to validate the cert of the site you're trying to hit, so it's bailing as a security measure.

Comment: my username and password are correct though, how do I make this SSL work out then ?

Comment: nothing to do with your user/pass. your request isn't even GETTING to the file because the ssl layer is not working.

Comment: Problem solved. If someone has the same problem while using Requests, just add as an option to your request Verify=False. This will bypass the SSL verification